# skipLocationChange not working perfectly

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, cesiumjs

I'm using skipLocationChange to navigate between 3 map components: Cesium, Leaflet and Openlayers 3. my Application is preserving location among the components as you can see in [mapmip.webiks.com](http://mapmip.webiks.com) (old version).
in order to set the bounds when moving from component to other I'm subscribe to the following function:

```
setQueryBoundsOnNavigationEnd(event:NavigationEnd):void {
let urlTree:UrlTree = this.leaflet.router.parseUrl(event.url);
urlTree.queryParams['bounds'] = this.getBounds().toString();
extras.skipLocationChange = this.skipLocationChange;
return this.router.navigateByUrl(url, extras);
 }
```

by this way

```
leaflet.router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd && event.url.includes("/cesium")).take(1).subscribe(this.setQueryBoundsOnNavigationEnd.bind(this));
```

but when I'm get back form cesium - the url is not hidden anymore.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was missing unsubsribe(), hence there were NavigationError and the state didn't load properly

Comment: hi I am getting same issue, on navigation change history is getting modified.
this.router.navigate(['/view'], { skipLocationChange: true });
how to fix this?